# What permissions are required for enumerating users groups in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have a .net web application which needs to obtain the groups a user is a member of in Active Directory.

Todo this I am using the memberOf attribute on the users records.

I need to know the permissions required to read this attribute on all users records.

Currently I am getting inconsistent results when trying to read this attribute. For example I have a user group of 30 users in the same OU path. Using my own credentials to query AD - I can read the memberOf attribute for some users but not others. I know all the users have a memberOf attribute set as I have checked when logged on with a domain admin account.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On your domain object, you need to assign the querying user the "Read MemberOf" right to User objects.

- Open AD U&C browse to your domain object
- Right click and go to properties: 
  [image: adu-n-c-domain]
  <sub>(source: [sysadmin1138.net](https://sysadmin1138.net/images/adu-n-c-domain.png))</sub>
- Security tab, click Advanced
- Click Add
- Enter the user name to add
- Click the Properties tab
- In 'Apply Onto' change the type to User
- Click the "Read MemberOf" checkbox:
  [image: ldap-read-member-of]
  <sub>(source: [sysadmin1138.net](https://sysadmin1138.net/images/ldap-read-member-of.png))</sub>
- OK out of there

That should set it up so that the specified account can read the group memberships of all User accounts in the domain.

Comment: Thanks sysadmin - I still cannot see a security tab when clicking properties on my test domain (its a server 2003 vm - set up by me.. a developer :P so could be wrong).. heres a picture of the properties screen I see. http://tinypic.com/r/10p7cdy/4

Comment: Ah, that's it. Go to View  and select Advanced Features. It'll show up once that's turned on. I always have that on so I forget that it's there :}

Comment: FWIW, this does not seem to apply to Windows Server 2012 where the Add dialog is quite different.

Comment: For the benefit of any users on Server 2008R2, these instructions are equally applicable, but the property tab is slightly different than what is described/pictured. The setting is labeled "Apply to:" and the correct value is "Descendant User Objects". All other instructions remain the same.

Comment: Many, many permissions... http://sysadmin1138.net/images/ldap-read-member-of.png

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and solved it on another level with a request to the AD:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(objectClass=top)(member=UserDN))
```

for the "dn" attribute.

As groups are readable by default, this will return an equal result to the "membersOf" property.

I know this is not really an answer to the permission question, but i landed here searching for a way to get the memberOf property without a permission-change in AD.