# Enumerating User Groups in Active Directory from Different Domain

Tags: active-directory

I have a .net web application that needs to obtains groups that a user is a member of in active directory.

My code works perfectly using my ID, but when I run it under the application ID it gives me the following error:

```
COMException (0x8007052e): Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
]
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +420085
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +36
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +31
   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList() +26
   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName) +49
   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName) +141
   System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.PropertyManager.GetPropertyValue(DirectoryContext context, DirectoryEntry directoryEntry, String propertyName) +57
```

The ID that I am using to run the application is in different domain than the users. I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/167371/what-permissions-are-required-for-enumerating-users-groups-in-active-directory) answer but I am not sure if it can apply to cross domain IDs.

What kind of configuration do we need for this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is Active Directory delegation. MSFT has a published [best practice document](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21678) that you can use. However its very [simple to implement](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Implementing-Active-Directory-Delegation-Administration.html). I also have a [simple step-by-step setup of delegation](http://umanage.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Active%20Directory%20Configuration) for an open source AD application I wrote that you can take a look at:

Comment: Thanks, Is "reading memberof" permission granted as a defult to all accounts in the same domain? Because I can see everyone's groups in my domain using NET command.

Comment: Pretty sure it is.  I can see the group membership of all Exchange groups by default and they are tied together.  Read is usually allowed regardless of user, write of course is not.